# AWS S3: Keep token file accessible to application, not to public users

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, key

I'm hosting a static website on S3 that uses an API. My auth token for the API is stored in a JS file, but I want to keep that obscured from public users, but NOT from my application.

At the moment, it looks like you need to make S3 buckets (and all of their files) publicly accessible by everyone, but I want to mask my config file. Is this possible, and if so, what is the best way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Amazon provides a service called [Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/). It is a serverless computing. You use can can be solved using this.

You can write an auth function in Lambda where you can place the api auth token.

Answer (score 0):

You are not really going to be able to completely hide your token, no matter what you do by masking it etc, ultimately your browser is issuing an API call and passing along the credentials which anyone that cares to look for it can see it.

What you want to do is use something like aws cognito to generate temporary, restricted tokens for each user, even anonymous users.

> Cognito Identity supports the creation and token vending process for
>   unauthenticated users as well as authenticated users. This removes the
>   friction of an additional login screen in your app, but still enables
>   you to use temporary, limited privilege credentials to access AWS
>   resources.

https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/faqs/

If you do this, someone can still see the token being used, but it is time and permission limited - not the keys to the kingdom, so they can't do much with it.